# Deadlock between goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm new to Go. When I comment out the second goroutine, there is a fatal error. I don't understand what causes this error to occur. Can you explain it to me?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() { 
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
    } ()
    // go func() { 
        for {
            if num, ok := <-ch; !ok {
                break
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%d\n", num)
            }
        }
    // } ()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    close(ch)
}
```

This prints the following code:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox169127128/main.go:17 +0xa0

Program exited.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The receiving for loop blocks on receive from `ch` after receiving all values from the sending goroutine. The runtime detects that the program is stuck and panics.

The fix is to close the channel after sending all values:

```
go func() { 
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
} ()
```

Receive on the closed channel yields the value `0, false`. The receiving for loop breaks on the false value.

Remove `close(ch)` from the end of the program.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/niuey98gzz).

Comment: Thank you for the succinct explanation, Cerise. I'm not sure I completely understand the idea of "blocking". 

Does this mean that the receiving for loop is stuck waiting forever? Is this because the ok on the left-hand side of the code below receives true, but there will never be another num to give?

if num, ok := <-ch; !ok

Comment: @Pizzas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing) In your case, `num, ok := <-ch` is blocking (waiting for another response). That other response never comes, because the sending go routine exited already. If you close the channel in the sending go routine, then another response (indicating that the channel closed) _is_ received.

Comment: @Pizzas  Receive on an open channel waits for a value to be sent to the channel.  The receive loop waits forever after all values from the sending goroutine are received.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not closing the channel before the first goroutine exits. The below code should work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() { 
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    } ()
    //go func() { 
        for {
            if num, ok := <-ch; !ok {
                break
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%d\n", num)
            }
        }
    //} ()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

Try it out here: https://play.golang.org/p/OdxNqbaZmj